# How can I show/change array contents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing the quiz from javascriptissexy.

Dynamically (with document.getElementById or jQuery) remove the current question and add the next question, when the user clicks the “Next” button. The Next button will be the only button to navigate this version of the quiz.

How can I remove the current question + list of answers and display the new ones dynamically? It works fine right now but think it's asking me to make the transition from questions smoother.

```
function nextQuestion(){

    j++;
    currentQuestion.innerHTML = allQuestions[j].question;

    for(var i = 0; i < allQuestions[j].choices.length; i++){
        currentChoices[i].innerHTML = allQuestions[j].choices[i];
    };

};
```

Comment: show some of your HTML

Comment: Can you please be a bit more specific in what exactly is not working? What is the expected behaviour and what does it do instead? Please also show all of the relevant code (not your entire page, but at least the code that you need to reproduce the issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before replacing the content, you must to hide, change the content and then show-it again

```
 $("#question").fadeOut("slow", function(){
     $("#question_content").html(allQuestions[question].question);
     for(var i = 1; i <= allQuestions[question].choices.length; i++){
          $("#choise"+i).html(allQuestions[question].choices[i-1]);
     };
     $("#question").fadeIn("slow");                    
});
```

Please see this example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/en4rt9o7/

Answer (score 0):

You can remove using the shift

```
    function nextQuestion() {
        var question = allQuestions.shift();
        currentQuestion.innerHTML = question.question;
        for (var i = 0; i < question.choices.length; i++) {
            currentChoices[i].innerHTML = question.choices[i];
        };
    };
```